# .net .vdproj - application shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut, vdproj

I'm creating a `.vdproj` setup for a simple Windows form.  I have added a shortcut to the user's program menu (in a folder), but when I click the shortcut, it just opens the install folder.  How do I set it up to run the .exe program?

I just tried putting the `.exe` name in the "Argument" for the shortcut - no luck yet.  I thought it might be more intuitive than that.  It also seems like "Target" might be the property to set - but it gives me a pick list - and my `.exe` is not in the list of things to pick.

Thanks,

Neal Walters

***Update 1:***

I'm using VS2008 SP1.

I added a folder under "User's Program menu" called "RCT" (that's my application name).  I right click on that folder and I see "Add" with an arrow to submenu and "Create shortcut to RCT".  The first thing I tried was the "Create shortcut to RCT", which is what lead me to post this question. Once the shortcut is there, it looks like the Properties Windows is the only way to configure it. 
I set the "Target", and "Working Folder" (all 3 properties) to "Application Folder". 
Now when I click the shortcut, it opens disk directory: C:\Users\uxnxw01\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\RCT

If I right click on "User's Program Menu" I see a link "Add shortcut to user's program menu".  I really want a shortcut "in" the user's program menu, not "to" the user's program menu.

The "Add" submenu has four options: Folder, Project Output, File, Assembly.

***SOLUTION - based on Heinzi's response:***

I think I got it now - you right-click on the white space (under "name ... type..."- not on the folder. Then I see "create new shortcut". What a confusing design on the part of Microsoft! Seems like you would click on the folder and "add new shortcut". Instead they give you "Add shortcut to..." the item you click on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clicking on `Create New Shortcut`, instead of selecting the application folder, *double-click* on the application folder. Then `Primary output from <YourApplication>` should be selectable.

Comment: Cool, Thanks.  So instead of clicking "Add shortcut" I should do "Add Project Output..."?   It worked, except I also get a shortcut to the config file.

Comment: No, "Add shortcut" (or "Create New Shortcut" as it is called in my version of Visual Studio (2008)) is correct. If you "Add Project Output", you get another *copy* of the exe into the start menu (rather than a shortcut), which is a bad thing.

So: (a) Add the Project Output to the application folder, and then (b) add a shortcut in the User's Program Menu by using the "Create New Shortcut" menu entry. *Inside* the "Create New Shortcut" window, double-click on the application folder to see the project output (which you have placed there in step (a)).

Comment: Also - how to change deploy directory from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\TFBIC.RCT.Monitor\ to C:\Program Files (x86)\TFBIC.RCT.Monitor\

Comment: I seem to be having a mental block - please see update 1 in my original question.  Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it now - you right-click on the white space (under "name ... type..."- not on the folder.    Then I see "create new shortcut".  What a confusing design on the part of Microsoft! Seems like you would click on the folder and "add new shortcut".  Instead they give you "Add shortcut to..." the item you click on.

Comment: And to change install location: click "Application Folder" then property "Default Location": [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\\[ProductName]  to [ProgramFilesFolder][ProductName]  (apparently Program Files Folder already has the backslash in it.

Comment: @Neal: Sorry, I saw your response only now. Yes, it's bad design that the option is not available in the folder menu. Glad to hear that it worked out for you, and thanks for updating the question with the solution!